# Using JQUERY, how to traverse down from a table element, and style all the TD elements of parent table and sub tables

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have a table, which contains tables, which also contain tables.

I would like to traverse through these tables of tables of tables with JQUERY, and style all of the TD elements to contain the style of   'padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;'

I assume that the first few statements would be like:

```
$('#overAllTableName tbody tr td').each().css('padding', '0px 5px 0px 0px');
```

Is this going down the right path?

Comment: .each() isn't needed.

Comment: Please don't add tags in the title if they don't fit in naturally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$('td').css({
  padding: '0px 5px 0px 0px'
});
```

or

```
$('#parentSelect td').css({
  padding: '0px 5px 0px 0px'
});
```

These jQuery selectors create an array which contains all of the td's you are looking for, the `each` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably already know the Firefox or Chrome console by pressing F12, and play around with Jquery commands. Jquery injector can help for web pages that don't already have Jquery: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-injector/indebdooekgjhkncmgbkeopjebofdoid?hl=ja.

The table itself has *cellpadding* property that you might want to play with.

If all the tables you want to update are inside the element #overAllTableName then this might do the trick:

```
$('#overAllTableName td').each(function() {
   $(this).css('padding', '0px 5px 0px 0px');
});
```

Comment: firefox sucks. use chrome developer